# SQL Assertion statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Consider the following two Relational Schema describing the EMPLOYEES and DEPARTMENTS of some organization (assume all names are unique).

```
EMPLOYEES (EmployeeName, Salary, DeptName)

DEPARTMENTS (DeptName, ManagerName, City)
```

Define at schema level, a constraint (SQL Assertion) which specifies that none of the salaries of the employees of any department located in ‘San Francisco’ is more than the salary of any employee in the ‘Management’ department.

My approach:

```
create assertion CHECK_SALARY as CHECK
(   

not exists (select * from EMPLOYEES

where select salary from EMPLOYEES

where EMPLOYEES.DeptName = 'San Fransisco' <

select salary from EMPLOYEES

where EMPLOYEES.DeptName = 'Management'

)
```

this is the thing i wrote but it is not working properly, any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: i tried it in oracle!

Comment: Your code seems to be missing every second line....

Comment: I think you are making a '<' comparison between many and many records. And that may not work.

Comment: Oh, i see, you just left out some parenthesis...

Comment: Since you mention you are using Oracle, I've removed the mysql and sql-server tags. Please don't tag products not in use.

Comment: Curious.  The question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135554/does-oracle-11g-support-create-assertion seems to suggest VERY clearly that oracle 11g does not support CREATE ASSERTION, not even just syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```sql
CREATE ASSERTION check_salary AS CHECK (   
  NO EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM employees
               WHERE ( SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees
                       WHERE "DeptName" = 'San Fransisco' )
                   < ( SELECT MIN(salary) FROM employees
                       WHERE "DeptName" = 'Management' ) )
);
```

Comment: why did you use sum(salary), it should be individual salary right?

Comment: Assuming that there are more than one employee in those departments, the sub-sub-`SELECT`s would return multiple rows. You cannot compare multiple rows, so you have to use an aggregate function, to get a single value. `SUM()` seemed to be a natural choice for `salary`...

Comment: (5 years later) I hate double negatives. The posted assertion is for asserting that the max salary in San Fransisco is always >= min salary in Management ... which probably NOT what is desired. This rule would prevent HR from potentially firing a "top paid undesirable".

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE ASSERTION check_salary AS CHECK (NO EXTISTS ( SELECT * FROM Employees ee, departments dd WHERE  ee.dept_name = dd.dept_name AND dd.city = 'San Francisco' AND ee.salary < (SELECT Max(salary_amount) FROM Employees e, Departments d WHERE e.dept_name =d.dept_name AND d.Dept_name = 'Management') ));
```